# When I click the listview button to play the sound on Android

Tags: android, audio, android-listview

I want to do the following;

[image]

When you click on the pictures, you want to play audio files. I looked at examples from the internet but could not find an answer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code

```
    playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
   MediaPlayer mysong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
      playbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


                           mysong.start();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MediaPlayer (refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)). Inside the onClick of ImageView, call the `start()` function for your requirement.